# modifying php email form into a smtp email form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, smtp

hi i have a self included email form so it doesn't require any other scripts i have run into a problem where i need it to send it via smtp but examples that i have seen are past my skill level i was wondering if some can help me

my email form is this:

```
<html> 
<head>
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Register.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="background-color:#303030">
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
?>
    <div id="login">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="can you create me an account"><br/>
       Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br/>
       first <input type="text" name="first_name" ><br/>
       last <input type="text" name="last_name" ><br/>
       company <input type="text" name="company" ><br/>
       email <input type="text" name="email" ><br/>
       Telephone number <input type="text" name="telnr" ><br/>
       Description <input type="text" name="Description" ><br/>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
    </form>
    </div>  

<?php 
    }
    else
  // the user has submitted the form
    {
  // Check if the "subject" input field is filled out
    var_dump($_POST);
if (isset($_POST["subject"]))
    {
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $first = $_POST["first_name"];
        $last = $_POST["last_name"];
        $company = $_POST["company"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $telnr = $_POST["telnr"];
        $description = $_POST["Description"];
        $therest = "First name= $first" . "\r\n" . "Last name= $last" . "\r\n" . "Company= $company" . "\r\n" . "Email= $email" . "\r\n" . "Telnr= $telnr" . "\r\n" . "Description= $description";          
    }
        echo "$therest <br>";
        $message = wordwrap($message, 700);
        $first = wordwrap($first, 70);
        $last = wordwrap($last, 70);
        mail("receiver@whatever.co.uk",$subject,$name,$therest,"subject: $subject\n");
        echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have PEAR MAIL package installed on the server? (not needed but I use it all the time)

Comment: @Daan currently no it isn't installed any ideas how to convert this form into an smtp authorized form or any ideas how i can

Comment: i was going to use class.phpmailer.php and class.smtp.php @Daan

Comment: Never used those sorry. Just look at the documentation.

Comment: @Daan What would be your way ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was no this form could not be changed into a `SMTP` email form what I needed to do was create a form that used PHPMailer and then I added the input boxes that I needed this has added more development into the website but it is actually working on the server that I was trying to reach